# Export part of schema to SpatiaLite

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I want to export a part of a schema to SpatiaLite.
It seems that I am to be able to export the whole schema with

```
gr2ogr -skipfailures --config PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES --config PG_SKIP_VIEWS YES -f "SQLite" /home/my_db_ogr.sqlite -progress PG:"dbname='dbname' active_schema=schema schemas=schema host='localhost' port='5432' user='user' password='password'" -lco LAUNDER=yes -dsco SPATIALITE=yes -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=yes -skipfailures -gt 65536
```

I would like to export single tables from PostGIS to SpatiaLite. But with

```
ogr2ogr  -append  --config PG_LIST_ALL_TABLES YES --config PG_SKIP_VIEWS YES -f "SQLite" /home/my_db.sqlite -update -append -progress PG:"dbname='dbname' active_schema=schema schemas=schema host='localhost' port='5432' user='user' password='password' tables='table I want to export" -lco LAUNDER=yes -dsco SPATIALITE=yes -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=yes  -gt 65536
```

I only get the error message that the file already exists and there are already layers there.

Does anyone have any ideas?
How can I export only some tables or some tables and a view from the PostgreSQL-PostGIS-Schema into SpatiaLite or geopackage?
How can I automate it?

Comment: Add `-update` for getting rid of the "file already exists" error.